# correctly treating NA values in SPSS .sav file imported into R using R's Haven package

Tags: r, r-haven

My platform is `Windows 10`

The data in my `.sav` file looks like this (the screenshots are from `PSPP` not `SPSS`):

Data View:

[image]

Variable View:
[image]

I'm using `haven` to import the `.sav` file into `R`:

```
library("tidyverse")
library("haven")
```

`haven` commands (my `.sav` filename is `spss_missing99.sav`):

```
> spss2 <- read_sav("C:/.../spss_missing99.sav")
> spss2

# A tibble: 11 x 1
   Points
    <dbl>
 1      1
 2      2
 3      3
 4      4
 5      5
 6      6
 7      7
 8      8
 9      9
10     10
11     NA


> is.na(spss2)

      Points
 [1,]  FALSE
 [2,]  FALSE
 [3,]  FALSE
 [4,]  FALSE
 [5,]  FALSE
 [6,]  FALSE
 [7,]  FALSE
 [8,]  FALSE
 [9,]  FALSE
[10,]  FALSE
[11,]   TRUE

> mean(spss2)

[1] NA
Warning message:
In mean.default(spss2) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA


> mean(spss2, na.rm = TRUE)

[1] NA
Warning message:
In mean.default(spss2, na.rm = TRUE) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

My question: why won't the last 2 `mean` commands work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are passing a dataframe/tibble to `mean` function, `mean` function works with a vector.

```
mean(spss2$Points, na.rm = TRUE)
#[1] 5.5
```

You can pass dataframe to `colMeans` function which will return column-wise mean of all the columns in the dataframe.

```
colMeans(spss2, na.rm = TRUE)

#Points 
#   5.5
```

Comment: Thanks Ronak! I wish the error message was more informative. I will mark your answer correct as soon as StackOverflow allows me (not enough time has lapsed since my question). Best.